# Wordpress Intranet Link Not Working

Tags: links

I'm having trouble creating a link that works for our pending Wordpress Intranet.  I don't have coding or web background so I've been trying to piece it together with info I find on the web.

This looks to be the UNC format, but when I try it, the link won't open the file or even download it (since I know Chrome won't view files anymore without an extension).

```
<a href="file://///int.xyz.com/files/office/testblankfile.docx">Network Link Test</a>
```

I did download the LocalLinks Chrome extension and the intranet link worked fine- downloaded the file and everything, but not everyone will use the same extensions, browsers, etc. so I'm looking for a solution that will cover IE, Firefox and Chrome.

I would like to avoid using a plugin at this time unless that's the only option.  Any help or direction with this is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be messy. You'll need browser extensions or per-browser settings, because you're basically asking the browser to access a file:// link which is not local to the machine, and I think many modern browsers have locked that down for security reasons.

Sorry I can't be the bearer of better news. :)

Comment: Thanks!  Is that the only way without a plugin or without getting into more complex methods?

Comment: Well there's nothing you can control server-side that I know of that will tell a browser to change how it handles 'file://' URIs, otherwise a rogue web page could cause havoc with browsers in many situations. So after some research, yes, I think each user would need to install an appropriate plugin, or you be at the machine to configure the browser differently.